# Can Geotools create a Geohash from a lat and lon?

Tags: geotools, geohashing

Recently I have been using the Geotools library (http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/) to process some simple geo data. However, the library is so robust that it is surprising to me that it doesn't seem to provide the capability to create geohash from a lat and lon.  Can anyone point me in the direction for documentation on how to use the Geotools library to create a geohash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a Java Geoshash library to do the task:

https://github.com/kungfoo/geohash-java

Following the Test Cases examples:

https://github.com/kungfoo/geohash-java/blob/master/src/test/java/ch/hsr/geohash/GeoHashTest.java

There are another libs:

- https://github.com/davidmoten/geo
- https://github.com/astrapi69/jgeohash

Java is rich in libraries and frameworks, use all you need :)